# how to compare search traffic percentage in Google analytics?

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to get a graph of search traffic percentage out of total visits over time.

I want to see if more percent of the visitors are coming from Google.

how can I generate such report?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just compare search traffic with all visits you can use the advanced segments and check the boxes labeled 'All Visits' and 'Search traffic'. For specifically filtering traffic coming from Google you can try writing a custom report with a filter set as follows:

1. Metric Group- Visits
2. Dimension Drilldowns - Source
   Filters
3. Include- Source - Regex - `.*google.*`
4. Include - Medium - Exact - organic